# LCD screen won't stop printing the same characters twice

Tags: lcd, switch, keypad

I'm hoping that someone might be able to help me figure out how to prevent my LCD from giving me double digits (i.e. 55, 66, 77 - instead of 5,6,7);

I have 2 functions that are printing, so I'm expecting the issue to be related to this.

Here's the code:

```
#include <Wire.h>

#include <Adafruit_LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <Keypad.h>

unsigned int deBounce = 100;
int curs = 0;


Adafruit_LiquidCrystal lcd(8, 9, 3, 10, 11, 12, 13);    

const byte numRows = 4; //number of rows on the keypad
const byte numCols = 4; //number of columns on the keypad

char keymap[numRows][numCols] =
{
  {'1', '2', '3', 'A'},
  {'4', '5', '6', 'B'},
  {'7', '8', '9', 'C'},
  {'.', '0', '#', 'D'}
};

char keymap2[numRows][numCols] =
{
  {'1', '2', '3', 'A'},
  {'4', '5', '6', 'B'},
  {'7', '8', '9', 'C'},
  {'.', '0', '#', 'D'}
};

//Code that shows the the keypad connections to the arduino terminals
byte rowPins[numRows] = {25, 27, 29, 31};
byte colPins[numCols] = {17, 19, 21, 23};

//initializes an instance of the Keypad class
Keypad myKeypad = Keypad(makeKeymap(keymap), rowPins, colPins, numRows, numCols);
Keypad myKeypad2 = Keypad(makeKeymap(keymap2), rowPins, colPins, numRows, numCols);

char enteredDigits[10]  = " ";//null terminated character array to hold entry
char enteredDigits2[10]  = " ";//null terminated character array to hold entry
boolean entryComplete = false;
boolean entryComplete2 = false;
boolean first = 0;

float result; // Create an integer for the result of 'A' and 'B' (in this case, it will be the 'Inductance' x 'Capacitance')
float power = .5; // Used in the equation
float r1; // Result 1
float r2; // Result 2
float r3; // Result 3
float r4; // Result 4
float fc; // Result 5
float power2 = 6; // Used in the last part of the equation
float result2 = 10; // Also used in the last part of the equation
#define TWO_PI 6.283185307179586476925286766559 // two Pi (:
float num1;
float num2;


void setup()
{
  myKeypad.setDebounceTime(deBounce);
  myKeypad2.setDebounceTime(deBounce);

  lcd.begin(16, 2);
}

void loop()
{
  getNumber();
  if (entryComplete)
  {
    entryComplete = false;
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    num1 = atof(enteredDigits);
    first = 1;
  }

  if (first == 1) {
    getNumber2();
    if (entryComplete2)
    {
      entryComplete2 = false;
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      num2 = atof(enteredDigits2);
      values();
      first = 0;
    }
  }
}

void getNumber()
{
  static byte index = 0;
  char key = myKeypad.getKey();
  if (key != NO_KEY)
  {
    switch (key)
    {
      case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
      case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9': case'.':
        lcd.print(key);//print entry on top row
        enteredDigits[index] = key;//build character string
        index++;
        enteredDigits[index] = '\0'; //null terminate
        break;

      case '#':
        lcd.setCursor(8, 0);
        lcd.print(F("= Ind."));
        delay(1000);
        entryComplete = true;
        index = 0;//reset for next entry
        break;

      case 'D'://clear entry and display
        memset(enteredDigits, '\0', 10); //clear buffer
        lcd.clear();
        index = 0;
        entryComplete = false;
        break;
    }
  }
}


void getNumber2()
{
  static byte index2 = 0;
  char key2 = myKeypad2.getKey();
  if (key2 != NO_KEY)
  {
    switch (key2)
    {
      case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
      case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9': case'.':
        lcd.print(key2);//print entry on top row
        enteredDigits2[index2] = key2;//build character string
        index2++;
        enteredDigits2[index2] = '\0'; //null terminate
        break;

      case '#':
        lcd.setCursor(8, 1);
        lcd.print(F("= Cap."));
        delay(1000);
        entryComplete2 = true;
        index2 = 0;//reset for next entry

        break;

      case 'D'://clear entry and display
        memset(enteredDigits2, '\0', 10); //clear buffer
        lcd.clear();
        index2 = 0;
        entryComplete2 = false;
        break;
    }
  }
}

void values() {

  result = num1 * num2; // If a 'comma' key is pressed (in this case, the # key on a 4x4 keypad)

  lcd.clear(); // Clear the writing from the LCD
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0); // Set the cursor position to the first block on the first line
  lcd.print(F("Ind. =")); // Display 'Ind. =' onto the LCD Screen
  lcd.setCursor(7, 0); // Set the cursor position to display after the previous text
  lcd.print(num1, 4); // Display the number value given to num1
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1); // Set the cursor for the first block on the second line
  lcd.print(F("Cap. ="));// Display 'Cap. =' onto the LCD Screen
  lcd.setCursor(7, 1); // Set the cursor position to display after the previoust text
  lcd.print(num2, 2); // Display the number value given to num2
  delay(2500);

  r1 = pow(result, power);
  r2 = r1 * TWO_PI;
  r3 = 1 / r2;
  r4 = pow(result2, power2);
  fc = r3 * r4;
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print(F("Res. Peak =")); // Display the answer onto the LCD Screen
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print(fc);
  lcd.setCursor(9, 1);
  lcd.print(F("(Hz)"));
}
```

Comment: I fear it's related to debounce time and the duration of pressing a keypad button. Is it always exactly duplicating the entries?  What about a debug output (Serial) to see more, what's going on?

Comment: Hmm, I didn't notice anything after changing the debounce settings. Even with a relatively high debounce (500 milliseconds), it still prints double.

Comment: If I take out this line from the getNumber2 function:

Answer (score 1):

I had to remove this line from the getNumber2 function!

lcd.print(key2);

works now (:

Comment: `keymap2` is not useful at all and just a duplicate. But having both keypads act on the same pins is your issue. Or don't you intend to have two keypads ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to break your code into parts and debug it part by part. Start by printing a single character to the LCD once, and setting a bool so you don't do it repeatedly. If that works, the LCD is not your problem.

As DataFiddler suggested, bounce problems with your switch seem like a likely culprit. Add serial print statements to your button handling code and see if it's being triggered more than once. If so, research debouncing code.